# Run node script from GUI?

Tags: node.js, user-interface, fs

I have a Node.js script.

I want to make GUI with a button and field. Input from the field will be used in a function in the script. I want clicking the button to execute the script (instead of the user having to use the command line).

The script uses multiple Node.js packages, like `fs` to write files. These packages aren't available in the browser. The script also has API requests that would be blocked by CORS policies. I've looked at using Electron or NodeGUI but I'm not sure if these are the right tools for the job.

The person I am building this GUI for does not want to pay or maintain a server.

What is the best way to create a GUI for this situation?

Comment: Why not just use a Node as web server? I think either your dev/production enviroment is over restricted, or you have an insufficient understanding of the client-server concept. So, will a simple HTTP GET request be blocked by your policies? If not then you can create simple web form as a client GUI which has nothing to do with any package of your Node script (fs, path, e.t.c.) since Node server will just listen incoming request and run your script as usual. If your network setup blocks any TCP request (please explain why) then Electron is pretty straightforward solution.

Comment: "these are the right tools for the job" - yes, they are

Comment: @mr.boris I forgot to mention a critical element: the person I'm building this application for doesn't want to pay for a server or maintain one themselves.

Comment: @Jack it is very difficult to say anything about using a web server in your case, because you did not specifically describe your application environment. Frankly, you don't need to setup dedicated server or pay for hosting in case when you run Node as web server locally in your network. Since you said that you are using console to run your script then you can bind web client GUI with Node server through localhost for free. But something tells me you better use Electron. On the other hand deploying or publishing Electron app as a legit certified software may require much more work.

Comment: I meant it is pretty straightforward task to make an Electron app just in development environment. But when your customer requests to publish an application that is easy to install, does not require administrator rights to run, and works on any platform, it will take a lot of effort for you. I.e. nowadays Electron apps are forbidden for uploading to the App Store, so that you must make your own website for further distribution or share it via some link.